Using the layout of a different struct pointer
TL;DR
If I have two structs that have the same layout for the first couple fields, say struct Athis and struct Bthat, can I take an instance of Athis and then reference it using Bthat with regards to accessing and/or modifying those initial members/fields?
Two different structs with initial identical layouts
Let's say I have the following 2 structs:
struct Athis { 
  int num;
  char *str;
  int *lst;
  unsigned int num_lst; 
  // end
};

struct Bthat { 
  int b_num;
  char *b_str;
  int *b_lst;
  unsigned int b_num_lst; 

  // more below
  char *b_not_b;
  bool b_hamlet; 
  long guildenst; 
  unsigned long rosencr;
};

Can I then do this, safely, all the time?
void do_stuff(struct Athis *a) {
  a->num += 2; 
}

void main() { 
  struct Bthat b = {0};
  b.b_num = 5; 
  b.b_str = "In hiss eeaarrrr...";

  do_stuff(&b);
}

In other words, if the layout/ordering of initial fields of 2 structs is identical, can I modify instances of either struct by casting them to only one of the two types/structs, as long as I limit myself to only modifying the initial "identical" fields?
Why?
I believe that somewhere in the HTSlib code, Marshall, Li and/or Bonfield do something like the above, which... surpised me, so to speak.
Then I ended up in my own code doing something where I have 2 very simmilar structs, and only have to access the initial fields of those structs -- and I thought of what they did.

Well, you can't do *a.num += 2; , but you can do a->num += 2;

As for your main question, see Are C-structs with the same members types guaranteed to have the same layout in memory?

It breaks the strict aliasing rule to access the other struct directly (unless they are both members of the same union, in which case the common initial members of the other struct can be accessed). The rules are a bit different for allocated objects (allocated by malloc, etc.).

This is how sockaddr works. https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sockaddr.3type.html

Why are there more answers in the comments than in the answer section, and only "comments" in the answers?!?

@Marco That question belongs in meta, but a quick reply from my viewpoint: The second comment established that the answer is "no", so maybe the most correct action would be to close the question as a duplicate, but I interpreted your last sentence as an unspoken question how to address this situation and thought it might add value to describe how this dubious construct can easily be avoided. As you have clearly expressed, this was not what you expected, but that is the answer your question triggered me to provide. Hopefully it will be useful for someone else.

In short, you can, but it will probably cause UB.
So, with regards to "safely, all the time" -- NO.

See https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sockaddr.3type.html for an example of the fact that it is/was possible at some point.

Thanks to @stark



However, there's a rule about strict aliasing in the standard.
That means that referencing one type as if it's another 1. breaks strict aliasing and 2. may cause a trap representation propblem.
The C standard does not guarantee that similar/identical structs will have  similar/identical layouts in memory.

Thanks to @ian-abbot and @some-programmer-dude


It is better to simply have an instance of struct Athis as a member of struct Bthat:
struct Athis { 
  int num;
  char *str;
  int *lst;
  unsigned int num_lst; 
  // end
};

struct Bthat { 
  struct Athis A;

  // more below
  char *b_not_b;
  bool b_hamlet; 
  long guildenst; 
  unsigned long rosencr;
};

Now you can:
void do_stuff(struct Athis *a) {
  a->num += 2; 
}

void main() { 
  struct Bthat b = {0};
  b.A.num = 5; 
  b.A.str = "In hiss eeaarrrr...";

  do_stuff(&b.A);
}

Notice that if A is the first member of struct Bthat, then a pointer to a struct Bthat instance can safely be cast to a pointer to a struct Athis.

@Marco No. It's an answer that provides a safe way to do what you want.

It's an answer to a different question, right? This is the answer to "How do I..". What's my question? If you look carefully, you'll see it says ".. can I.."

How about adding a third structure
struct Common {
   int num;
   char *str;
};

Change your structures to
struct Athis { 
   struct Common c;
   int *lst;
   unsigned int num_lst; 
   // end
};

struct Bthat { 
   struct Common c;
  unsigned int b_num_lst; 

  // more below
  char *b_not_b;
  bool b_hamlet; 
  long guildenst; 
  unsigned long rosencr;
};

If you wish to operate on Common
void do_stuff(struct Common *a) {
  a->num += 2; 
}

Test
void main() { 
  struct Bthat b = {0};
  b.c.num = 5; 
  b.c.str = "In hiss eeaarrrr...";

  do_stuff(&b);
  /* If compiler objects, try
  do_stuff(&b.c);
  do_stuff((struct Common*)&b);
  */
}


In the OP, int *lst is also a member of Bthat so the entire Athis is common with the beginning of Bthat. Sorry, but apart from this discrepancy, I do not see how this answer differs from my answer.
